# How to solve cross Thread Operation not valid in windows form?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, ado.net, tcpclient

I have been stuck here .....I am creating a  chat server windows application,which will host and all client will register

let me explain my scenario,when i start a chat server.....I have used TextBox name ChatTextBox,in which i try to get all registered client Ip address

But when i try to register a client on server it shows cross thread operation is not valid,how to solve it ????

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Net;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Threading;

namespace Myservercheck
{
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    TcpListener myli;
    TcpClient clientSocket = default(TcpClient);
    string s=string.Empty;

    public Form2(TcpListener tc)
    {
        myli = tc;
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    private void Form2_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        IPlistBox.Items.Add(myli.LocalEndpoint.ToString());
        chattextBox.Text= "Chat server started on selected IP & Port Number:\n"+myli.LocalEndpoint.ToString();
        chattextBox.AppendText("\n");
        chattextBox.AppendText("Waiting for connections............\n");
        myli.Start();
       Thread thread1 = new Thread(listern);
       thread1.Start();
        chattextBox.AppendText("\n");


    }


    public void listern()
    {
        while (true)
        {

            clientSocket = myli.AcceptTcpClient();
            IPAddress tempAddress = ((IPEndPoint)(clientSocket.Client.RemoteEndPoint)).Address;
            chattextBox.Text = tempAddress.ToString();
            chattextBox.AppendText("Connection accepted from:" + s);
        }
        }
    }




    }
```

Comment: You can solve it by typing ""WinForms cross thread operation" in Google. You will find many answers on this site alone.

Comment: I am new,i have seen its is done using delegates and using Invoke i did not know how??I am unexplained...why its done using delegates and invoke

Comment: The same question has been asked and answered many times here. See the __Related__ column on the right of this page.

Comment: Look [Background Worker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc221403%28v=vs.95%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to invoke a method on the form control to delegate to the form's thread. You can only access form controls from the same thread that created the form.

```
public void listern() {
    while (true) {
        clientSocket = myli.AcceptTcpClient;
        IPAddress tempAddress = ((IPEndPoint)(clientSocket.Client.RemoteEndPoint)).Address;
        UpdateChattextBox(tempAddress.ToString, "Connection accepted from:" + s);     
    }
}

public void UpdateChattextBox(string address, string message) {
    if ((chattextBox.InvokeRequired == true)) {
        this.invoke(UpdateCattextBox, address, message);
    }
    else {
        chattextBox.Text = tempAddress.ToString;
        chattextBox.AppendText(("Connection accepted from:" + s));
    }
}
```

Comment: _"only access form controls from the same thread that created..."_ is true but very unhelpful.